# Connecting Table1 th width to Table2 td width

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I have a table (*table1*) which contains only `th` tags and a table (*table2*) which contains only `td` tags. (I know this set up seems really wrong, but it's set up this way due to a few different issues with the application, so try not to worry about why it's set up this way).

Each `TH` in *table1* acts as a sorting button corresponding the `TD` in *table2*.

The full width of each table is the same, however the width of the `TH`'s and the `TD`'s are different making them not line up correctly.

I need to find a way to link the width of each individual `TH` to the width of the `TD` below it. The difficult part is that the `TH` sorting buttons are dynamic and the user has the ability to add or remove `TH`'s to their liking, so the widths need to be able to dynamically change. I can't figure out how to link the two together seamlessly. Any ideas?

IE:

```
<table id="table1">
 <thead>
 <th>Sorts 1</th>
 <th>Sorts 2</th>
 <th>Sorts 3</th>
 <th>Sorts 4</th>
 </thead>
</table>
<table id="table2">
 <thead>
 <td>Sort 1</td>
 <td>Sort 2</td>
 <td>Sort 3</td>
 <td>Sort 4</td>
 </thead>
</table>
```

I have created a basic Fiddle that shows what mean. The last few `td`'s get squished into the Sorts7 column. I want the `TH` and the corresponding `TD` to always equal the same width, even if we add or remove columns.

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TBankston/6u1dyL55/)

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The two tables do have to remain separate. It's unfortunate I know. :(

Comment: Do the two tables have to be separate? Because you could do this: https://jsfiddle.net/CalvT/6u1dyL55/8/

Comment: Unfortunately yes. If I could keep them together it would be so much easier. Basically the reason has to do with an infinite-scroll / virtual repeat window containing the second table and a scroll to top function not running correctly if the tables are connected. @CalvT

Comment: Are the column widths all going to be the same?

Comment: No. Just like in the Fiddle, some will be longer than others. The actual tables is about 1800 rows, so the TH just needs to match the widest TD. @CalvT

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't like this answer, but it works so...

What you could do is use `jQuery` to get the widths of the bottom columns and apply it on the top columns - like this:

```js
$('#top1').css({"width":$("#bottom1").width()});
$('#top2').css({"width":$("#bottom2").width()});
$('#top3').css({"width":$("#bottom3").width()});
$('#top4').css({"width":$("#bottom4").width()});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
 <thead>
 <th id="top1">Sorts 1</th>
 <th id="top2">Sorts 2</th>
 <th id="top3">Sorts 3</th>
 <th id="top4">Sorts 4</th>
 </thead>
</table>
<br> <!-- To demonstrate that they are separate -->
<table id="table2">
 <tr>
 <td id="bottom1">Sort 1</td>
 <td id="bottom2">Sort 2 With Longer Content</td>
 <td id="bottom3">Sort 3</td>
 <td id="bottom4">Sort 4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td id="bottom1">Sort 1</td>
 <td id="bottom2">Sort 2</td>
 <td id="bottom3">Sort 3 With Longer Content</td>
 <td id="bottom4">Sort 4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I just hope you don't have a lot of columns!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a same class for both th & td.

Comment: Even if the width should dynamically change based on the width of the text inside? @Poonam

Comment: Yeah! I prefer fix width responsive design for my data tables and class thing works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

I've used jQuery because of simplicity:

```
$( "#table2 tr td" ).each(function( index ) {
    $('#table1 th').eq(index).css('width',$(this).width()+'px');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6u1dyL55/10/

So, idea is to get td widths, and attach it to corresponding TH's in first table (via indexes - because they are same).